# How to calculate the integral of $ \int\frac{1}{\cosh^{2}x}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

Ofcourse one can notice that

$ \left(\frac{\sinh\left(x\right)}{\cosh\left(x\right)}\right)'=\frac{\cosh^{2}\left(x\right)-\sinh^{2}\left(x\right)}{\cosh^{2}\left(x\right)}=\frac{1}{\cosh^{2}\left(x\right)} $

But im looking for a straight way to prove that

$ \int\frac{1}{\cosh^{2}x}dx=\frac{\sinh\left(x\right)}{\cosh\left(x\right)}+ C $

Here's what I tried:

$ \int\frac{1}{\cosh^{2}x}=\int\frac{1}{1+\sinh^{2}x}dx=\frac{\arctan\left(\sinh x\right)}{\cosh x} + C$

Now im not sure how to continue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your attempt is wrong, check the derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment to another answer, you want to show that $\displaystyle \int  \mathrm{sech}^2 x dx = \tanh x + c$.

I find the easiest way is to use complex numbers. Start with the circular trigonometric version $\displaystyle \int  \sec^2 x dx = \tan x + c$, which I assume you can assume or you know how to prove. Then transform to the hyperbolic trigonometric version with the substitution $x=iy$:

Note that $\cos iy = \cosh y \implies \sec iy = \mathrm{sech}\ y$ and $\tan iy = i\tanh y$.

$\displaystyle \int  \sec^2 iy d(iy) = \tan iy + c$

$\displaystyle i\int  \mathrm{sech}^2 y dy = i\tanh y + c$

$\displaystyle \int  \mathrm{sech}^2 y dy = \tanh y + z$

where $z$ is an arbitrary complex constant. If you're dealing with a purely real domain, $z$ will be real as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of evaluating this integral.  You can let $t=\text{tanh}{x}$ so $\text{cosh}^2{x}=\frac{1}{1-t^2}$ and $dx=\frac{dt}{1-t^2}$:
$$\int \frac{\frac{dt}{1-t^2}}{\frac{1}{1-t^2}}= \int \; dt = t + C = \text{tanh}{x}+C$$

You can also rewrite $\text{cosh}^2{x}$ as $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$ and let $u=e^x$ to evaluate this integral.

Comment: Thanks, but its just writing the problem in a different form. I'm looking for the proof that $ \int sech^2xdx=\tanh x+C $

Comment: So wait.: In order to do this, you already have to know the derivative $\frac{d}{dx} \tanh x$?

Comment: By quotient rule: $\frac{d}{dx} \text{tanh}{x}=\frac{\text{cosh}^2{x}-\text{sinh}^2{x}}{\text{cosh}^2{x}}=\text{sech}^2{x}$

Comment: So if you know that, you are done, no need to talk about "substituion".

Comment: Thats what I posted for the original answer but OP said he wanted it without the simple answer.  And if you read his question description he knows it's the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to circular trig functions if you are more comfortable with them, and then back again.

$$ x\rightarrow iy \;;  \; y \rightarrow x/i \; ;  $$

$$ \int \text{sech}^2{x} \; dx\rightarrow \int \text{sech}^2{iy}\; idy \rightarrow \int \text{sec}^2{y} \;idy $$
$$= i\; \tan y  = i\tan \dfrac{x}{i} = i\tan \dfrac{ix}{i^2} = \dfrac{i^2}{-1}\cdot\tanh x $$
$$ = \tanh x $$

Answer (score 0):

In order to do integrals involving hyperbolic functions, you will need to know the basic derivatives:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \sinh x = \cosh x
\\
\frac{d}{dx} \cosh x = \sinh x
\\
\frac{d}{dx} \tanh x = \operatorname{sech}^2 x
$$
You will not get very far without knowing at least these.

Looking at the third line, you already know
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\cosh^2 x} .
$$

Answer (score 0):

With $u=e^{2x}$ this is$$\int\frac{2du}{(u+1)^2}=\frac{-2}{u+1}+C=\tanh x+C-1.$$